# Usage of words in correct context

Tags: vocabulary

I am trying to learn new vocabulary. So i try to make stazas on whatever words i learn in a day. One of the paragraphs is

> The movie director focused excessively on the minutiae details of the
>   character and the movie turned out to be ponderous. The pith of the
>   movie is love triumphs in all forms. Anyone can watch the trailer to
>   get the gist of the movie but I would never suggest anyone to watch
>   the movie. It will only attenuate your pocket. Romance is more
>   prevalent in bollywood and hollywood these days but there is a huge
>   disparity in the way it is portrayed on the big screen. The paucity of
>   kissing scenes and the ubiquitous scenes of emotional drama in
>   bollywood can bore anyone to death. This movie has only ossified my
>   distrust in romantic bollywood movies. There are no vestiges of hope
>   that this movie will outperform any of the movies by the same
>   director.

I want to know if this paragraph has any vocabulary and grammar issues.

Comment: To start with, "minutiae" is a noun.  "Minute" is the corresponding adjective.

Comment: @Hot Licks...can you suggest some edits to make this question active.

Comment: As it says above, a specific source of concern in the text must be clearly identified.  You can't give us a wall of words and ask us to proofread it.

Comment: @Hot Licks..I did not know about this in the past. Do you think this question can be edited in some way.

Comment: You can select a few passages that you have specific questions about.

Answer (score 1):

I have a few thoughts that you may hopefully find useful:

- "Minutiae" is already a noun, meaning the small or trivial details of something. "Minutiae details" is redundant (the "small details details"). You would rather say either that he focused on the minutiae, or that he focused on the *minute* details.
- You don't normally suggest someone "to" do something, you suggest ("to" them, perhaps) "that" they do it. In your sentence, I would write, "I would never suggest that anyone watch the movie."
- "Attenuate" is typically used to refer to something intangible, such as a metaphorical concept or something like a radio or audio signal, in the context of being reduced in value. When a physical object is described as attenuated it means stretched out and thin. When I read "attenuate your pocket," I imagine my pocket being pulled and stretched out before I think of "devalued."
- Both Bollywood and Hollywood should be capitalized. Hollywood is the proper name of an actual city, and Bollywood is a portmanteau of "Bombay" and "Hollywood," both proper place names.
- A "disparity" is between two or more things, or within one larger thing or concept. You are trying to say that there is "a disparity in the *ways* it is portrayed" (a single way it is portrayed does not by itself demonstrate disparity). Alternatively, you could say there is "a disparity in its portrayal on the big screen" (the portrayal, in this case, is the larger concept that contains the disparity).

Overall, this is a neat idea and I think you've done well!

Comment: @geekahedron...Sir, such questions are downvoted a lot. But your answer is very useful for me.Is there any way I can contact you by messages. It will prove to be very useful for my preparation.

Comment: Questions about proofreading ("Is this right?", "Are there any mistakes?"), unless a specific source of concern is clearly specified, are out of scope on this site

Comment: @Cascabel That's why i was asking if there is any way i can message any person who can help me on this site. My main motive is to learn english vocabulary and i think native speakers can help me best in this regard.But the downvotes to this question have made me worried.

Comment: I don't think anybody here will share their email on the main out of privacy concerns. If you want proof-reading there are other sites to choose from...just don't ask me where they are coz I don't know.